# php Работа с массивом

Tags: php, json

У меня есть json-ответ [`service_id.json`](https://uzpay.biz/api/rest/json/service_id_3.json), я хочу получить `['areas'][$i]['name']` и `['areas'][$i]['children']['areas'][$s]['name']`. Их надо вывести в json-формате.

Мой код:

```
$array = json_decode($arrayj, 1);
$response['data'] = array();
for($i = 0; $i < count($array['areas']); ++$i) {
  $response['data']['name'][$i] = $array['areas'][$i]['name'];
  for($s = 0; $s < count($array['areas'][$i]['children']['areas']); ++$s){
    $response['data']['name']['subname'][$i] = $array['areas'][$i]['children']['areas'][$s]['name'];
  }
}
echo json_encode($response);
```

Ответ получается вот такой:

```
{"data":{"name":{"0":"Andijon viloyati","subname":["Kuygan yor ETK","Buxoro shahar ETK","Jizzax shahar ETK","Qarshi XETK","G'ozg'on ETK","Namangan Energosotish","Dehqonobod ETK","Termiz XETK","Yangiyer shahar ETK","Yangihayot ETK","Yangiyo'l shahar ETK","Marg'ilon shahar ETK","Xisha shahar ETK","Taxiatosh ETK"],"1":"Buxoro viloyati","2":"Jizzax viloyati","3":"Qashqadaryo viloyati","4":"Navoiy viloyati","5":"Namangan viloyati","6":"Samarqand viloyati","7":"Surxondaryo viloyati","8":"Sirdaryo viloyati","9":"Toshkent shahri","10":"Toshkent viloyati","11":"Farg`ona viloyati","12":"Xorazm viloyati","13":"Qoraqalpog`iston Respublikasi"}}}
```

Но вывести нужно вот так:

```
data->name->0 = Andijon viloyati
data->name->0->subname = Kuygan.......
data->name->1 = Buxoro viloyati
data->name->1->subname.....
```

Answer (score 0):

Если вы хотите работать с массивом, то надо писать так:

```
json_decode($response, true);
                       ^^^^^
```

Если надо работать с объектом и проблема с   `->0` и `->1`  то надо писать так:

```
data->name->{0} = ...
            ^^^
echo data->name->{0}->subname // тут можно только геттер а не сеттер если в 0 не StdClass
            ^^^
```